Ubuntu 20.04 P2V Vmconverter
I am facing the below issue during P2V conversion using vmconverter.
--> description = "GrubInstaller::InstallGrub: /usr/lib/vmware-converter/installGrub.sh failed with return code: 127, and message:
--> FATAL: kernel too old
--> Error running vmware-updateGrub.sh through chroot into /mnt/p2v-src-root
--> Command: chroot "/mnt/p2v-src-root" /vmware-updateGrub.sh "GRUB2" "(hd0)"(hd0,2)" /vmware-device.map "grub2-install"
--> "
--> msg = "An error occurred during the conversion: 'GrubInstaller::InstallGrub: /usr/lib/vmware-converter/installGrub.sh failed with return code: 127, and message:
--> FATAL: kernel too old
--> Error running vmware-updateGrub.sh through chroot into /mnt/p2v-src-root
--> Command: chroot "/mnt/p2v-src-root" /vmware-updateGrub.sh "GRUB2" "(hd0)" "(hd0,2)" /vmware-device.map "grub2-install"
--> '"


You'll have to contact VMware on this.  It looks like the kernel running on 20.04 is "too old" for the vmware converter to process on.
